# I need find way to make correct queries Redirect 301?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a question about redirect query 301...

Old Link: `https://example.com/about.php?lang=1`
New Link: `https://example.com/about`

I try a lot of samples for rules for .htaccess, but can't find rules for redirect queries, if someone can help share the work query?

Sample that i'm try it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang\=1$ 
RewriteRule ^/?about\.php$ example.com/about? [L,R=301,QSD,NC] 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)lang\=1($|&) 
RewriteRule ^about\.php$ nalyvky.com/about [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngone on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)lang=1(&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?about\.php$ /about [QSD,R=301,L]
```

It externally redirects all requests to `https://example.com/about.php?lang=1` to `https://example.com/about` by means of a 301 http response.

Often such redirection is combined with an internal rewrite to be able to process such redirected requests:

```
RewriteEngone on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)lang=1(&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?about\.php$ /about [QSD,R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/?about/?$ /about.php?lang=1 [L]
```

This assumes that the http host is irrelevant for the setup, your question is a bit fuzzy in that ...

Comment: You'll need to add the `QSD` flag to discard the original query string in the redirect.